# I have one array [ 1,2 , 3,-4,-1,4] and want it to be sorted in order [-4,1,-1,2,3,4]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array **[1,2,3,-4,-1,4]** and want it to be sorted in order **[-4,1,-1,2,3,4]**.  i am separating positive and negative array in new array and sorting by index.Is there any simple way to print?

Comment: JavaScript? Java? AJAX? Swing?

Comment: What language are you using ?  You've tagged `java` and `javascript`

Comment: **shorting bye index** and **sepreting possitive and negative array**??

Comment: Why does `1` come before `-1`? Provide full rules of your sort criteria. Also please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: .sort((a,b)=>a-b);

Comment: My guess is that he wants negatives sorted on odd (or even) indices while positive on even (or odd).

Comment: You sort order is not clear. Please clarify a bit more.

Comment: i want preserve insertion order

Comment: what's the order.

Comment: If you want help you need to provide a more concisely detailed explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. Also show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: {1,2,3,-4,-1,4} this is my input array and i want output array as like this {-4,1,-1,2,3,4} . First i want negative number from input array then positive number

Comment: That order is not obvious what sorting rules/criteria are and you need to put a lot more effort into explaining them. People here don't have crystal balls and can't read minds

Comment: So, the sorting rule could be described by 1) Sort the numbers in ascending order. 2) Split the negative and positive (sorted) numbers into separate collections. 3) Starting with the collection of negative numbers, insert them into a collection of all numbers alternately from negative and positive collections, until one collection is entirely added. 4) Add the remaining numbers in the other collection, in order. ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean `[-4,-1,1,2,3,4]`: You could use JavaScript's `sort()`-method. You can read about this method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).